# How to get static web site hosting in Azure Storage working with a folder tree?

Tags: angular, azure, azure-storage, single-page-application, azure-blob-storage

Basically I have an angular project I want to get hosted on azure storage. It's basically consists of the regular bundles and a few folders with images, etc..

I followed this guide here for setting up a static web site on Azure storage: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-static-website Basically uploaded index.html and 404.html to the $web container.

So far so good, but then how to create subfolders to place images etc.?

Comment: can you make a screenshot of the settings page?

Answer (score 3):

There are no folders in Blob Storage, basically.

If you want to upload an image image.jpg and put it into the folder images, you would name the blob like this:

```
images/image.jpg
```

All the tooling uses prefix filtering to show you virtual folders which do not actually exist.